# How can I write an asynchronous input function for my chatroom mock-up?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7, curses

I'm new to asyncio, aioconsole and curses. I'm writing a mock-up for a chatroom which is supposed to run with aiortc. I want to mock the p2p connections between all the clients in the chatroom. I've built a cli with curses and am now trying to write an asynchronous input function for user input. How can I integrate aioconsole's ainput in my curses window?

I have included evchat's classes for the cli. (https://github.com/EvanKuhn/evchat/tree/master/evchat)
I have also implemented a producer/consumer procedure which produces random output and prints it to the console. In general it mocks an active chat between several people. Without the user input the program runs as expected. It generates a random chat history just without user input.

```py
import os
import json
import datetime
import asyncio
from aioconsole import ainput
import sys
import random
import curses
import ui

from loremipsum import get_sentence

class Prompt:
    """
    #==============================================================
    # The Prompt class prompts the user for text.
    #==============================================================
    """
    def __init__(self, layout, screen):
        self.layout = layout
        self.screen = screen
        self.window = curses.newwin(layout.prompt_rows, 
                      layout.prompt_cols,
                      layout.prompt_start_row, layout.prompt_start_col)
        self.window.keypad(1)
        self.window.addstr('> ')

    def getstr(self):
        "Get an input string from the user"
        return self.window.getstr()

    # ... more functions, more classes


class Message:
    """
    #================================================================
    # Message class
    #================================================================
    """
    def __init__(self, time=None, name=None, text=None):
        self.time = time
        self.name = name
        self.text = tex


class ChatApp:
    """
    #========================================================== 
    # The ChatApp class is contains all lower-level UI classes, plus 
    the main
    # runtime loop.
    #==================================================================
    """
    running = False

    def __init__(self, config, arguments):
        self.config = config
        self.layout = ui.Layout()
        self.args = arguments
        self.screen = None

    # ...more functions

    async def generate_output(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        """
        generates random output for mockup purposes, 
        the producer
        """
        name_list = ["Sepp", "Schorsch", "Hansi", "Hildegard", "Vreni"]
        time_delay = random.uniform(0.1, 2)
        rand_name = random.randint(0, 4)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        randtext = Message(now, name_list[rand_name], 
                           str(get_sentence(True)))
        # self.history.append(randtext)
        await asyncio.sleep(time_delay)
        await queue.put(randtext)

    async def user_input(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        """
        getting user_input
        the producer
        """
        # Get input
        # text = self.prompt.getstr()
        text = asyncio.wait_for(self.prompt.getstr(), timeout=1)
        # Construct and store a Message object
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        msg = Message(now, self.config.name, text)
        await asyncio.wait_for(queue.put(msg), timeout=0.1)

    async def write_to_console(self, queue: asyncio.Queue):
        """
        coroutine for writing to console, 
        the consumer
        """
        while True:
            msg = await queue.get()
            self.history.append(msg)
            queue.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ChatApp(conf, args)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        task = loop.create_task(app.start())
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        app.stop()
```

I expect Sepp & Co. to write random ipsum sentences in random intervals without the user input preventing the chat participants to write stuff. Like in a whatsapp or whatever chat group.
At the moment I'm only getting this: I write something to the chat. only one person replies and everyone is waiting for another input from the user.

what didn't help was this in the Prompt class:

```py
async def getstr(self):
    "Get an input string from the user"
    text = await self.window.getstr()
    return text
```

or:

```py
async def getstr(self):
    "Get an input string from the user"
    text = await ainput()
    self.window.addstr(text)
```

To be honest I have no clue how to get the ainput into my curses window. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create another task that specifically waits for an input and then calls `addstr`.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. But the problem is that curses' windows which I'm using block for user input. and i am not able to integrate non-blocking input into such a window's getstr() function

Comment: It seems that only window.getstr() is allowed. Other input functions don't have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than [getstr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getstr), you can make your own function using [getch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch), with a short [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.timeout) (or with [nodelay](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.nodelay) set).

Comment: did that but it lags so much. Feels rather like synchronous.

Comment: That depends on how much delay you add.